# How can I use substrate_frame_rpc_system & sc_client_api modules on substrate-node-template project?

Tags: substrate-node-template

Everyone.
I am getting this error.
Here is my Codebase: https://github.com/WB-Expert5007/Poa_to_Pos
Please help me.

```
Compiling node-template v4.0.0-dev (/home/mersaid/Documents/HARRY/Task/Climacoin/node)
error[E0432]: unresolved import substrate_frame_rpc_system::LightSystem
--> node/src/rpc.rs:196:35
|
196 | use substrate_frame_rpc_system::{LightSystem, SystemApi};
| ^^^^^^^^^^^ no LightSystem in the root

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find light in sc_client_api
--> node/src/rpc.rs:61:48
|
61 | pub remote_blockchain: Arc<dyn sc_client_api::light::RemoteBlockchain>,
| ^^^^^ could not find light in sc_client_api

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find light in sc_client_api
--> node/src/rpc.rs:192:20
|
192 | F: sc_client_api::light::Fetcher + 'static,
| ^^^^^ could not find light in sc_client_api
```

Here is Error Image.

[image]

Please help me.
Best Regards.

Comment: Have you tried looking at those missing impls in the upstream source? I guess you copied code from a different version of substrate. AFAIK all light client related things in substrate have been removed.

Comment: Please do not include screenshots. You have the text above, just pit it in markdown code blocks please 

Comment: Thanks very much.
Sure, I have looked at missing impls in the upstream source and I knew light client related things has been removed.

So then, what should I do now?
Could you give me any project I can reference to convert consensus engine of current substrate-node-template(v4.0.0) project from PoA to PoS, please?

Now I am referencing this project, https://github1s.com/kaichaosun/tao/blob/HEAD/node/src/service.rs#L31.
As you know, that's version is 2.0.0.
So I need to change many modules and funtions.

Please help me.
Best Regards.